# Why doesn't std::remove_const remove const qualifier?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, type-traits, decltype

Note that I use `std::thread` just to get readable types in the errors:

```
int main() {
    const int * first;
    using deref = decltype(*first);
    std::thread s = std::remove_const<deref>::type{}; // const int ???
    std::thread s2 = deref{}; // const int
    std::thread s3 = std::remove_const<const int>::type{}; // int 
}
```

It seems as if `remove_const<deref>::type` is `const int`, not mutable `int` as I would expect.

Comment: I would recommend you use [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfccfe0a5508f107) to show types instead of your `std::thread` method because it shows the actual type which is `const int &` whereas your method lies to you and shows `const int`.

Comment: `mutable` is a storage class specifier, not part of a type.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Note that `*first` is an lvalue expression, then the result type of `decltype(*first)` would be `const int&`, i.e. a reference to `const int`. The reference is not `const` itself (it can't be const-qualified, there's no such thing like `int& const`), using `std::remove_const` on it will yield the same type, i.e. `const int&`.

See [decltype specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

> 3. If the argument is any other expression of type `T`, and
>
> b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then `decltype` yields
> `T&`;

You could use `std::remove_const` with `std::remove_reference` together:

```
std::remove_const<std::remove_reference<deref>::type>::type // -> int
                                        ^^^^^               // -> const int &
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        // -> const int
```

---

BTW:

> Note that I use `std::thread` just to get readable types in the errors:

Note that it doesn't give the correct type for this case. Here's a class template helper for this from the [*Effective Modern C++* (Scott Meyers)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996):

```
template<typename T>
class TD;
```

and use it as

```
TD<deref> td;
```

You'll get the error message containing the type of `deref`, e.g. from [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H2o6fpAzQBDQsRjF):

```
prog.cc:16:11: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<const int &>'
TD<deref> td;
          ^
```

Comment: Aaaand this is why you should write `int const &` instead of `const int&`... then the answer to the question is obvious.